# What is wrong with these for-loops that make my program stop running?

Tags: c, function, for-loop

These functions that contain a for loop are supposed to check whether in a vertical movement in a chess game there is a piece between the initial coordinates and the final coordinates.
It's supposed to check columns (vertical only).

These are run in another function that checks whether the attempted move is valid.

However, once I run my program with this code, if in fact these functions are run the code stops. I'm not sure if all the processes stop but it doesn't print anything it should print.

I'm pretty sure the problem is within this code because without it my program runs correctly.

I tried changing the identifiers in the for loops but that didn't work. I believe the problem is related to adding 1 to "fromr". Without doing this, the code runs just fine. But I need the function to check from the piece below fromr and not fromr itself.

```
int checkVerticalPathwayWhite(int fromr, int fromc, int tor){
    fromr = fromr + 1;
    for(int r = fromr; r < fromr; r++){
        for(int c = fromc; c == fromc;){
            if (board[r][c] != &empty){
                printf("Pathway is not clear\n");
                return 0;
            }
        }
    }
    printf("Pathway is clear");
    return 1;
}

int checkVerticalPathwayBlack(int fromr, int fromc, int tor){
    fromr = fromr - 1;
    for(int r = fromr; r > tor; r = r-1){
        for(int c = fromc; c == fromc;{
            if (board[r][c] != &empty){
                printf("Pathway is not clear\n");
                return 0;
            }
    }
}
    printf("Pathway is clear");
    return 1;
}
```

I expect the function to return 0 if there is a non-empty piece in the pathway between (fromr+1) to (tor-1) and 1 if there isn't.

Comment: `for(int c = fromc; c == fromc;)` is an infinite loop since `c` will always be equal to `fromc`.

Comment: Your conditions for the loop are wrong. `r==fromr` will always result is `r<fromr` being false. Also your inner loop does not have an increment and will run indefinitely

Comment: In the 1st for loop in `checkVerticalPathwayWhite`, `r < fromr` should be `r < tor`.

Comment: It's also not clear why the functions are called `white` and `black` instead of just `down` and `up`. For example, a white rook in the middle of the board can move vertically in either direction.

Answer (score 1):

Your conditions for the loop are wrong.

1. `r` is initialized to `fromr`. The condition `r<fromr` will always be false.
2. `c` is initialized to `fromc`. The condition `c==fromc` will be true, but you do not have an increment in the loop. So the loop will run infinitely.

Comment: Sorry about that, but it was only a typo here. It's actually r<tor in my program

Answer (score 0):

```
for(int c = fromc; c == fromc;)
```

That's an infinite loop. I guess you'd want to change c somehow.

Comment: I actually want c to stay the same since I only want to check a column. Is this what's messing up with my program? How can I fix this and still have c not change?

Comment: In that case you don't need a for loop at all. You'd use a for loop to iterate over few columns

Comment: So how can I iterate over a few rows in one column in a matrix?

Comment: If you want to iterate over all cells of a specific column `c` you'd `for(int r = fromr; r > tor; r = r-1){ do_something_with(board[r][c]); }`. Just the outer loop is enough. And I guess your function should receive `c` as an argument instead of `fromc`.